# Using angular and trying to email contents of div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, email

So I have a div with a class name and am trying to figure out how I can inject the rendered components of that div as text into the body of an email. All things for my email works and I have tried using a class, an ng-model, etc... to do this. Nothing working yet.

My part of the controller handling the email:

```
$scope.Subject = "Moneyball Problem Phase Worksheet"
$scope.bodyText = '{{ problemExp }}';

$scope.mailLink = "mailto:" + $scope.emailId + "?subject=" + $scope.Subject + '&body=' + $scope.bodyText;
```

and the div with the class and ng-model that once rendered, when to include:

```
    <div class="problemExp" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 15px; margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc;" ng-model="problemExp">      
        <div>
            <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">HYPOTHESIS:</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;" id="hypCriteria">We believe that <span style="color: blue;">{{ criteria || '[criteria]' }}</span> of <span style="color: blue;">{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> are most frustrated about <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> because <span style="color: blue;">{{ problem || '[problem]' }}</span>.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab; margin-top: 25px;">CUSTOMER SCREENING CRITERIA:</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">We are looking for <span style="color: blue;">{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> who are regularly involved in <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>.</p>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab; margin-top: 25px;">CUSTOMER INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">Tell me about the last time when you were <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">What are the major challenges with <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">On a scale of 0-10, how frustrating are these problems? Why?</p>            
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">If you could wave a magic wand and be able to do anything about <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> in your daily job, what would it be?</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Again, I only want the text, not the html elements.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) command:

```
$scope.bodyText = angular.element('.problemExp').text();
```

This will produce the following output:

```
// HYPOTHESIS:
// We believe that {{ criteria || '[criteria]' }} of {{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }} are most frustrated about {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }} because {{ problem || '[problem]' }}.


// CUSTOMER SCREENING CRITERIA:
// We are looking for {{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }} who are regularly involved in {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}.


// CUSTOMER INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:
// Tell me about the last time when you were {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}?
// What are the major challenges with {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}?
// On a scale of 0-10, how frustrating are these problems? Why?            
// If you could wave a magic wand and be able to do anything about {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }} in your daily job, what would it be?
```

If you need more control over how you process and output the text content the html, you can use jQuery's [contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) function to get the contents of each `p` node:

```
var out = "";
var paragraph = $(".problemExp").contents();
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (paragraph[i].nodeType != 3) out = out + paragraph[i].textContent + "\n";
}
console.log(out);
```

This code will result in the following output:

```
// HYPOTHESIS:
// We believe that {{ criteria || '[criteria]' }} of {{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }} are most frustrated about {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }} because {{ problem || '[problem]' }}.

// CUSTOMER SCREENING CRITERIA:
// We are looking for {{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }} who are regularly involved in {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}.

// CUSTOMER INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:
// Tell me about the last time when you were {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}?
// What are the major challenges with {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}?
// On a scale of 0-10, how frustrating are these problems? Why?            
// If you could wave a magic wand and be able to do anything about {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }} in your daily job, what would it be?
```

Comment: thanks for the info. WHat I am after is it not include the actual tags, but the text generated here. Where you see the {{ "" }}, I simply am after the text filled in for that from a form elsewhere. Thoughts on how to achieve that?

Comment: Angular should render the embedded expressions `{{ criteria }}` before this code runs so it will print out the rendered text.  Did it not do that?

Comment: correct - it simply puts the following in the email body:         HYPOTHESIS:    We believe that {{ criteria || '[criteria]' }} of {{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }} are most frustrated about {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }} because {{ problem || '[problem]' }}.            CUSTOMER SCREENING CRITERIA:    We are looking for {{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }} who are regularly involved in {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}.     CUSTOMER INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:Tell me about the last time when you were {{ (task != null) ? task : '[task.......

Comment: It sounds like Angular isn't rendering the expressions.  Are you sure Angular is running properly?  Do you see the text rendered properly on the screen?  Maybe this jQuery code is running before Angular has had a chance to finish compiling/rendering?  There's a deeper problem here that you need to find.